# How do I to create a security policy by profile using Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a system using Asp.Net MVC, but before I start to develop I need to define the security policy. I thought to create it by profile where each profile will have permissions to access, for example: Profile Administrative (all permissions), Profile Common (restrict access), Profile Manager (with some permissions of profile Administrative).

I thought to create a Profile with Permissions by *Method's Name or Controllers* and give permissions as boolean true/false, example: The method `addNewProduct()`, whether this method only works to Profile Administrative/Manager I will give permissions only for them, however, I don't know how could I do to get the Controller or Method's name to give these permissions.

Example:

**Profiles**

```
Administrative      |   Common             |   Manager
[x]addNewProduct    |   []addNewProduct    |   [x]addNewProduct
```

How could I do this ? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is not *profiles* but *roles*, and the technique is called *Role-Based Authorization*.

In ASP.NET MVC, you can use it like this:

```
[Authorize] //ensure a user is signed-in
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrative,Manager")] // ensure the user is signed in and belongs in one of the roles
    public ActionResult DoSomething()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here, if, for example, `Windows Authentication` was enabled, the `Authorize` attribute would look for the user's `Groups` in `Active Directory` to confirm whether the user belong to one of those groups or not.